# Methods for Improving Convergence of a sequence of Partial Sums

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation, irrational-numbers

I have the following sum:

$$\zeta(3)+\frac1{4}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{2k^2+7k+7}{(k+1)^3(k+2)(k+3)}$$

Are there any methods that I can use to speed up the convergence of the sequence generated by taking the partial sums?  I have not found anything on-line, but I also don't know much about how to do this type of transformation while keeping the limit of the sequence the same.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_acceleration is devoted to such tricks. It is also interesting to recall, from Apery's work, that: $$\zeta(3)=\frac{5}{2}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^3\binom{2n}{n}}.$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there is the [Euler-Maclaurin Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula). Not guaranteed to work, but it may be worth a shot.